# Can we say "transfer function" is almost same as black box, in context of mathematical modelling of physical systems?

Tags: control, control-system, signal-processing, transfer-function, signal-theory

In context of mathematically modelling of physical systems,can we say that representation of a system using "transfer function" form is almost same as black box form? Is it ok/correct? As for example transfer function of integrator is **-1/RCs**.

So we then represent integrator by black box having **-1/RCs** displayed on it.

Comment: I understand what the transfer function form is but, regarding the black-box form, it's probably not defined. If you can provide any definition for what a black-box form is it would help.

Comment: "Black box" generally means "box with unknown contents". You might choose to view a defined transfer function as more of a "white box" or clear box; since you know the transfer function.

Comment: I will consider transfer function as a white box since we know what is inside it.